# Install Mac OS X Tiger alongside Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos

I have recently installed a 1TB hardrive on my **Mid-2010 MacBook Pro**. I understand that it is possible to install **Windows 7** through BootCamp (by partitioning the hardrive) on Snow Leopard but is it possible to install **OS X Tiger** as well?

I have an install disk for **OS X Tiger** from (MID -I am assuming) 2005 but I am unsure as to how I would accomplish this. Would this be possible by any means? (legally and within the bounds of Apple's EULA of course)

My current OS is **OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lion 10.7 was the first consumer Mac OS to be licensed for virtualisation [OS X Server 10.5 was actually the very first]

No Mac can boot natively on an OS from before it was manufactured, as the drivers to support that hardware weren't yet invented.

There is a distant chance you may be able to get [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/uk/products/desktop/resources/) [list is for current version, not compatible with Snow Leo anyway] to virtualise Tiger [even though it is against the EULA], but I would be doubtful.
[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) supports Leo & Snow Leo Server, not Tiger.

It might be simpler, if not cheaper, to get an old Mac that would run Tiger natively.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, I'm afraid. When Apple releases a new model, they add support (drivers, config info, etc) into the current version of OS X (and release it in the form of a new build or version of OS X). Support for that model is never added into older versions of OS X. As a result, your mid-2010 will not be able to run any version of OS X released before mid 2010. No 10.4, no 10.5, not even 10.6.0 through 10.6.2.